# Force OUTSIDE_TOUCH-event?

Tags: android

I'd like to dismiss the system volume popup (to replace it with my own implementation). The system volume popup is a dialog that has set the `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH`-flag. When physically touching my own view (that's being displayed alongside the system dialog), the system dialog is correctly dismissed, but calling

```
myView.performClick();
```

or

```
mView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

(where `motionEvent` is an `ACTION_DOWN`-event) does nothing. The source for the system volume dialog can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/VolumePanel.java).

Comment: You want to programmatically control the System UI? That sounds like it could be a security risk, so probably quite tricky. Explain a bit more & provide some code & context pls

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier, I've updated the question with some more context and a reference to the relevant Android source.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Thx for the info, I removed my downvote. I don't think this is going to be possible / easy, and I have no idea. Good luck, I'll be watching for an answer to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just a matter of dismissing the system volume dialog, the following piece of code should work:

```
// We will use android.app.Instrumentation to send a MotionEvent
Instrumentation mInstrumentation;
....
....

// We cannot use the main application thread. Note that this is a requirement.
public void dismissSystemDialog() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendMotionEvent();
        }
    });

    t1.start();
}

public void sendMotionEvent() {
    if (mInstrumentation == null) {
        mInstrumentation = new Instrumentation();
    }

    // These values should satisfy two requirements:
    //     1. They don't map to a point on the System dialog.
    //     2. They DO map to a point that is part of your UI.
    //        Perhaps, your own dialog: use `getLocationOnScreen(int[])`
    //        for this. 
    int y = 700;
    int x = 50;

    final MotionEvent m = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
                                             SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                             MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
                                             x, y, 1);

    try {
        mInstrumentation.sendPointerSync(m);
        Log.i("", "Dismissing Volume Dialog Now...");
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.i("", "Security Exception." + 
                      " Permission `INJECT_EVENTS` is not granted");
    }
}
```

The code is self-explanatory. And I hope that it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Vikram, thanks for the answer. This requires the [INJECT_EVENTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INJECT_EVENTS)-permission, which is a system-level permission that isn't granted to third-party apps.

Comment: @Nick Can you post the relevant code? You should be seeing this exception only when your `MotionEvent` coordinates fall outside your UI. Not otherwise.

Comment: Hi Vikram, my app runs as a service, but I just tested your code again and it does indeed work :-)! I was just thrown off by the Exception (and I had previously tried the inject-events-approach and it didn't work). The volume-dialog unfortunately has a slow fade in/fade out animation, so it is still being shown for 1-2 seconds, but this is obviously not "your fault" and you answered the question correctly, so I'm awarding the bounty to you :-). Thanks again!

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the prompt update. Just a thought: If you are showing a personalized volume control, perhaps you can show it "on top of" the system dialog. This way, you'll at least keep the user from seeing the fade-out transition. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score -1):

you can either use `mDialog.dismiss()` or `Activity.dismissDialog(int)` to manually start dialog dismissal yourself.

Comment: I don't have any control over the system dialog, so this won't work.

Comment: oh, I thought you meant a stock dialog created by your app..
In that case, I don't think it is possible or permitted. System dialogs are meant to be dismissed by the actual user, not hidden by an app.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more context. It isn't a traditional system dialog that I want to dismiss, but the system volume popup (which is implemented as a dialog).